# C# non-class obj to JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax

I have several objects containing few variables in my js that are sent to c# with an ajax call. Is there a way to send that same object from c# to js as a json without creating a special custom c# class?
for example i have an object containing several paramaters that are sent to the db to retrieve some data. I want to be able to send those paramaters from c# so i can manipulate them on js.

Comment: What do you mean by custom class? You can certainly reuse your existing class and simply serialise the object using any serialiser, e.g. JSON.NET.

Comment: Have you tried serializing anonymous objects?

Comment: Or if you don't want anonymous objects have you tried just creating the json objects using whatever json library you are using?

Comment: Can you show us what code you have?

Comment: thanks @Chris thats exactly what i was looking for, wasnt aware of anonymous objects

Answer (score 0):

Use anonymous type object

```
Var xyz = new {prop1="val1",prop2="val2"}
```

Convert to json string. Return it to js.

Answer (score 0):

use the JavaScriptSerializer class and Anonymous objects 
you need to import it the JavaScriptSerializer

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
//...
var obj = new {a="a", b="b"};//...
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
```

then simply return it